Unit test Panache with PanacheMock outside a Quarkus project
We've got the following setup:
- parent
 - service + orm (lib)
 - processor (jberet, quarkus deployable)
 - api v2 (REST, quarkus deployable)
 - api v3 (REST, quarkus deployable, to-be)
 - app (quinoa, quarkus deployable)

The service encompasses the business logic (service) + the object-relational-model used by all other deployables (Quarkus applications) that run in their own pod's. We are using Panache and Panache-mock to unit test.
However, we run into the problem that it seems we need to annotate the tests in the service lib with @QuarkusTest in order to test. That requires application.properties and the Quarkus plugin and basically spins up a Quarkus application.
Is there a way around this? So not making the lib project de-facto a Quarkus application?
Note 1: only putting an application.properties in the test folder will most likely work. But it would be nice if we could Panache + Panache-mock without a need to start Quarkus.
Note 2: the Quarkus projects have different POD scaling demands.
Moreover, we try to keep the access layers in the Quarkus applications thin. So, for example, just map from REST to Service and mock the service classes in unit test in the Quarkus application, so in essence following a tiered architecture in which the

Quarkus applications form the Access-tier or Presentation-tier only.
and where the Business-tier is implemented in the service (lib) module (service package)
and the Data-tier is respectively also implemented in the service (lib) module (orm package)

